# Javascript: "TypeError: $(...).html(...).html(...).css is not a function"

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

i'm trying to write a function which counts the number of syllables in a piece of text, i know it won't be that accurate, it's just a simple version I need at the moment which roughly counts the number of syllables.

```
whenkeydown = function(max_length) {
$("#my_text").unbind().keyup(function() {
    //check if the appropriate text area is being typed into
    if (document.activeElement.id === "my_text") {
        //get the data in the field
        var text = $(this).val();

        function countSyllables(words) {
            console.log(words);
            for (var z; z < words.length; z++) {
                word = word[z].toLowerCase();                                     
                if(word.length <= 3) { return 1; }                             
                word = word.replace(/(?:[^laeiouy]es|ed|[^laeiouy]e)$/, '');   
                word = word.replace(/^y/, '');                                 
                syllables = word.match(/[aeiouy]{1,2}/g).length; 
                syllableCount += syllabes   
                }              
        return syllableCount
        }

        var syllableCount = countSyllables(text)

        $("#noOfSyllables").html("").html(syllableCount).css("color", "#F7860C"); //orange
```

The error i get in the (aptana/firefox) debugger is "TypeError: $(...).html(...).html(...).css is not a function", does this mean my function does not return anything?

Comment: Setting the html() to nothing and than to another value is a useless step. There is no reason to blank it out.

Comment: Are you sure that you are linked the jquery library source?

Comment: @sємsєм yes i have, 
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    Syllable Count: <em><span id="noOfSyllables"></span></em>
in my html file
and

Comment: @epascarello oh yes, that was copied from another line where i change the colour of the text based on how many characters are there, for which i need to set it to nothing, but yes you're right, it is unnecessary on this line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your variable `syllableCount` is never set in your function `countSyllables`.

I expect to see a `var syllableCount = 0;`

```
function countSyllables(words) {
    var syllableCount = 0;
    ...
```

second issue.

You are treating text() as if it returns an Array. It is a single string.

Comment: oh yes, that was stupid of me, that fixes the error, although i still get a value returned of zero regardless

Comment: Because it looks like `words` is supposed to be an Array and it is a single string. :)